# How do you unlock Costumes in Trivial Pursuit Live

Tags: trivial-pursuit-live

How do you unlock Costumes in Trivial Pursuit Live?

I looked around but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the UPlay app
2. Go to Trivial Pursuit Live
3. Tab over to Rewards
4. Go down to All Rewards
5. Unlock the costumes you want:

   - 10U: Eagle Eyed Expert Skins
   - 20U: Master Chef Skins
   - 30U: Director Look
   - 40U: Galactic Explorer Skins

*** Note that you HAVE to choose the unlocked title to be able to select the appropriate costume - selecting it, picking your costume then changing the title again REVERTS back to it being unlocked ***